# How do I modify the content of an HttpEntity

Tags: java, apache, http, httpentity

I've got an `HttpResponse` with an `HttpEntity` (all from `org.apache.http`).

My `HttpEntity` has some application/json content that I want to modify before sending it forward.

I can read the content as a string with

```
EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

But how do I store the modified content of my entity back into my response?

Comment: Looks like `EntityUtils.updateEntity(...)` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using `EntityBuilder`.

```
response.setEntity(EntityBuilder.create().setText(newText).setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `toString` method is used to 'print' an object. Most of the time, you'll use the `toString`method for logging. You should rather access the variables you want to read or modify via the getters. For example:

```
reponse.getEntity().getContentEncoding().getName();
reponse.getEntity().getContentEncoding().getValue()
```